# padding leading zeros in a column using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I would like to left pad with "0's" on first column say (width 14)

input.txt
`17: gdgdgd`
`117: aa`

Need the out put as below

```
00000000000017: gdgdgd
00000000000117: aa
```

i have tried the `awk -F: '{ printf "%14i: %s\n", $1,$2 }' input.txt` but it's working

padding more than `%09i` Nine is not working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try

```
awk -F: '{ printf "%014i: %s\n", $1,$2 }' input.txt
```

see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html)

> A leading ‘0’ (zero) acts as a flag that indicates that output should
>   be padded with zeros instead of spaces. This applies only to the
>   numeric output formats. This flag only has an effect when the field
>   width is wider than the value to print.

Comment: Thanks, i want to apply this for 1 column. say 5th column in a file. How can i modify this?

Comment: 5th column(field) represented by `$5`, print $5. This is affected by the field separator.

Comment: in my case I needed to act on second column `awk -F, '{ printf "%s,%04i,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9 }' input.txt`